# How to localize Android OS for new locale

Tags: languages, localization

I've been looking for the Android "localization project", assuming that there is one (like you have for LibreOffice or Mozilla) but so far, I have only found thousands of pages about localizing apps, but nothing about the operating system itself. Which suggests it's more complicated than I expected...

- Assuming that it can be localized, anyone know if end users can then download and install such a new locale on their phones? I'm under no illusions about Scottish Gaelic ever getting shipped by default :/
- If the answer is yes, then does anyone know how the localization process for Android actually works and where I need to go?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on manufacturer. What's your device?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a copy of the OS with the needed locale. Since it's part of the OS it can't be added by a simple app download or anything. You can [Spoof your locale string on any device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&hl=en) but that app doesn't actually offer localizations beyond what shipped on your phone; it won't translate system text ect unless your phone has those localizations native.

As per the [Android SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html#locs):

> Note: The Android platform may support more locales than are included in the SDK system image. All of the supported locales are available in the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/).

You'll have to reflash your device with a system image that has your locale; the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/) includes more locales but you/someone would have to actually compile them into a working system image/ROM. Making it work on your device is also another matter; ideally if your manufacturer has another official ROM out there with the locale on it you want, you should find that ROM and use it.

Unfortunately I don't know of any sites that have ROMs by supported locale.